# Know the stack trace of a hibernate object updating methods

Tags: java, hibernate

A database table is facing waits in updating sometimes, this entity is being updated from many locations/ associations,

Is there a way to get the stack trace of the method updating that entity?!

I override `onFlushDirty` method of `Interceptor` so I could know when the entity is being updated, but I need to know the trace from where this entity has been called to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could just log the stacktrace: [`Thread.getCurrentThread().getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Keep in mind, that this is a performance expensive way. So, you should use guard statements in order to prevent this logging in your production environment, e.g.:

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    // log stacktrace
}
```

Another option would be to use your IDE. Most IDEs, like Eclipse, can show you the "Call Hierarchy" of any method.
It might not apply to your current code, since you might not be using DAOs to encapsulate data storage, but it might be a more efficient way.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, it would help. Unfortunately I want to put that on a deployed testing version, and to check the logs later. The `getStackTrace` would help, but I'm afraid of the performance. I was looking for a more efficient hibernate way, like Interceptors.

Comment: I don't get the problem. You want the stacktrace, so you have a method for that. If you fear its performance (which at this point is premature), make sure you don't call it when you don't need too.

Comment: I just updated the answer. You should use guard statements to prevent logging in production.